# XSLT on Tree XML

Tags: xml, xslt

Here is my XML

> ```
>          <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
>        <Root>
>         <Personal>
>            <Admin>
>               <Code>111</Code>
>            </Admin>
>            <Report>
>               <DataSet>
>                 <History>
>                   <Claim no="1">
>                      <Subject>
>                         <Name>
>                            <First>John</First>
>                         </Name>
>                      </Subject>
>                  </Claim>
>                  <Claim no="2">
>                      <Subject>
>                          <Name>
>                             <First>John</First>
>                          </Name>
>                      </Subject>
>                  </Claim>
>             </History>
>          </DataSet>
>     </Report>
>  </Personal>
>   <Personal>
>            <Admin>
>               <Code>222</Code>
>            </Admin>
>            <Report>
>               <DataSet>
>                 <History>
>                   <Claim no="1">
>                      <Subject>
>                         <Name>
>                            <First>Don</First>
>                         </Name>
>                      </Subject>
>                  </Claim>
>                  <Claim no="2">
>                      <Subject>
>                          <Name>
>                             <First>Don</First>
>                          </Name>
>                      </Subject>
>                  </Claim>
>             </History>
>          </DataSet>
>     </Report>
>    </Personal>
>   </Root>
> ```

Here "Personal" Section will repeat multiple times[dynamic].

I want the data as

> ```
>     John
>       Don
> ```

On Click of John data must expand as

> ```
>     John 
>           Admin
>           Report
>             Claim: 1
>                Name: John       
>             Claim: 2
>                 Name:John
>        Don
> ```

I created XSLT for this as below:

> ```
>     <?xml version="1.0" ?>
>       <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
>       <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" />
>       <xsl:key name="keyName" match="Personal" use="Report/Dataset/History/Claim/Subject/Name/First" />
>        <xsl:template match="Root">
>        <ul>
>          <xsl:for-each select="Personal[generate-id() = generate-id(key('keyName', Report/Dataset/History/Claim/Subject/Name/First)[1])]" >
>          <xsl:sort select="Admin" />
>           <li>
>       <xsl:value-of select="Report/Dataset/History/Claim" />
>       <ul>
>         <xsl:for-each select="key('keyName', Report/Dataset/History/Claim/Subject/Name/First)" >
>           <li>
>             <xsl:value-of select="Name"/>                
>           </li>
>         </xsl:for-each>
>       </ul>
>     </li>
>   </xsl:for-each>
> </ul>
>   </xsl:template>
>  </xsl:stylesheet>
> ```

I am not getting data as expected.. Please guide me here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is (probably) due to XML being case-sensitive. In your XML you have this:

```
<Report>
    <DataSet>
```

But in your key (and when you use the key), you do this:

use="Report/Dataset/History/Claim/Subject/Name/First" />

So, the XML has `DataSet`, but your key uses `Dataset`, which are different. Your key needs to be like this

```
<xsl:key name="keyName" match="Personal"   
        use="Report/DataSet/History/Claim/Subject/Name/First" />
```

And similarly for when you use the key.

Another issue is with your `xsl:for-each`

```
    <xsl:for-each select="key('keyName', Report/DataSet/History/Claim/Subject/Name/First)" >
      <li>
        <xsl:value-of select=Name"/>                
      </li>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

You are positioned on a `Personal` element here, so the `<xsl:value-of select=Name"/>` needs to be relative to that

```
<xsl:value-of select="Report/DataSet/History/Claim/Subject/Name"/>
```